# How to move a text upper in HTML?

Tags: html

I've already tried many ways to move a text up in HTML so that it can be seen in Live Server, but unfortunately it didn't work.

So my question is, how can I move a text that is visible in Live server up?
I'm attaching some pictures in case it helps.
Here is the pictures!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyHPm.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZMUr.png

Thanks for help!
Levee999

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode  -->> https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: the description is not clear and the images are not helpful. please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There are errors in your code try

```css
*,body{
margin:0;}
#about{
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyHPm.jpg);
height:100vh;
}
.section-inner{
color:#333;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<main>
<section id="about">
<div class="section-inner" >
some text here.....
</div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope This will help :)